# Why doesn't my port forwarding work

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I've got a Netcomm NB9W router and I'm trying to forward ports 7 and 9 for wake on lan.

I've set up a static IP address and I've configured both these ports using the Advanced\NAT\Port Forwarding option, but when I query the ports using either an online tool or PFPortChecker from Portforward, I'm told the port is not open or reachable.

Using the port scan utility in Mac OSX I can only see that 21,22,23,80 etc are open.

I've tried adding incoming ip filters for these ports but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your settings on the router? Are you querying from *inside* your network? Forwarding will only work from outside.

Answer (score 0):

A computer that is asleep doesn't have a IP address, so forwarding UDP 9 to a static address for wake on LAN doesn't work. You need to forward the port to a broadcast address. For a typical home network on 192.168.0.0 and with a network mask of 255.255.255.0 network the broadcast address would be 192.168.0.255.

Comment: Good answer, but any idea why I can't open the ports on the router?

Comment: Are you sure it is the router that isn't working and not a firewall on the machine that is blocking it? I believe most machines are running a discard service on port 9, and so discarding the packets. Try creating a specific rule for inbound UDP 9.